# Sync ImageReader and SurfaceTexture with Android Camera2 output

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-camera

ImageReader and SurfaceTexture is async from app side. `SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener` and `ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener` are coming in different time.

Now I will make an AR App. I calculate the object motion with the image from ImageReader and output the object motion information. On the other hand. Call `updateTexImage` to render background. But the question is the object motion has obviously latency behind background rendering.

The workflow is below:

Camera2->ImageReader->calculate object motion -> Render a virtual object with object motion information

Camera2->SufaceTexture->Render backgroud with `updateTexImage`

the `upateTexImage` and rendering-virtual-object is call in `Render.onDrawFrame`

So obviously the question is how to Sync ImageReader and SurfaceTexture with Android Camera2 output

Comment: Call `updateTexImage` firstly. it will update the timestamp. and then get surface's timestamp. THIS IS the key action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest option is not to use two data paths, and instead either do image analysis on the SurfaceTexture buffer (either in EGL or read back from GPU to CPU for analysis), or use the ImageReader buffer to draw everything with.

If that's not feasible, you need to look at the timestamps (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html#getTimestamp() and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Image.html#getTimestamp()). For the same capture, the two paths will have the same timestamp, so you can queue up and synchronize your final drawing by matching them up.

Comment: I can queue up `Image` from `ImageReader`. But I have no idea that how to access `SurfaceTexture` data or control the texture update using timestamp. Can you give me more information?

Comment: SurfaceTexture is somewhat hard to control, since it double-buffers internally and discards any old frames in queue if new frames arrive.  But after you call updateTexImage, getTimestamp will tell you what time that frame was captured, and you can find a matching Image from your ImageReader to it.  Then you can render that pair together.